# Getting `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` even though i am using `for update` in the query?

Tags: apex, trigger, update

We have a APEX trigger that updates large number of (10,000 aprox) contact owners in asynchronous fashion. Even though I am using `for update` keyword when querying the contacts for update I am still getting following error.

```
error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record
```

Here is the method that gets called where I am getting this issue.

```
public static void updateContactOwners (List<Id> contactIds, Map<Id, Id> wholsesailerPerTerritory) {
    List<Contact> updatedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id, Territory__c, OwnerId from Contact where Id in :contactIds for update];

    for (Contact contact: contacts) {
        if (contact.OwnerId != wholsesailerPerTerritory.get(contact.Territory__c)) {
            contact.OwnerId = wholsesailerPerTerritory.get(contact.Territory__c);
            updatedContacts.add(contact);
        }
    }
    System.debug('total contacts to update' + updatedContacts.size());
    update updatedContacts;
}
```

I there something else that I need to do to  get this to work ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this method, but I would return this `List`,  where else are updating these `Contacts`?

Comment: Do all these 10000 contacts map to the same account?.It can result in Account Skew issue

Comment: @RedDevil never heard of that before, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html

Comment: @EricSSH - Check this link, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/reducing-lock-contention-by-avoiding-account-data-skews.html

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) discusses the possibility of another process already having the lock:

> If you attempt to lock a record currently locked by another client,
>   your process waits for the lock to be released before acquiring a new
>   lock. If the lock isn’t released within 10 seconds, you will get a
>   QueryException. Similarly, if you attempt to update a record currently
>   locked by another client and the lock isn’t released within 10
>   seconds, you will get a DmlException.

You mention that you have a:

> trigger that updates large number of (10,000 aprox) contact owners in asynchronous fashion

so one of your asynchronous processes may be blocking another of your asynchronous processes from obtaining a lock.

If that is the case you can e.g. [check the job queue](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_monitoring) when you get an exception (or every time) and defer the additional work until later. Bit tricky to get right though.

Comment: All of them run in a mutually exclusive fashion so one async instance doesn't block another

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh Yep that is what is needed. Are you sure your approach to achieving that works?

Comment: well its spanning different future tasks from a set of Ids which insures no dupes